# OmniAuth Login With Twitter - "Did not recognize your adapter specification." Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been following railscast **Login with Twitter** using *Omniauth* tutorial.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

However, I am getting `Did not recognize your adapter specification` error.

You can find the `Application` error trace in the following.

By the way, I tried with both using `multi_json` *1.7.9* and `multi_json` *1.8.2*:

```
ArgumentError (Did not recognize your adapter specification.):
  multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json.rb:108:in `rescue in load_adapter'
  multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json.rb:97:in `load_adapter'
  multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json.rb:101:in `load_adapter'
  multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json.rb:91:in `use'
  multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json.rb:73:in `adapter'
  multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json.rb:131:in `current_adapter'
  multi_json (1.8.2) lib/multi_json.rb:118:in `load'
  omniauth-twitter (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:34:in `raw_info'
  omniauth-twitter (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:17:in `block in <class:Twitter>'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:106:in `instance_eval'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:106:in `block in compile_stack'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `each'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `inject'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `compile_stack'
  (eval):7:in `info_stack'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:322:in `info'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:335:in `auth_hash'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:362:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:58:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `callback_call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:182:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4245266409247275268__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/share/ruby/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/share/ruby/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread
```

Comment: I dont see here in the backtrace your code, it is strangely, Please provide us your code, which do request to the twitter?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I ran

```
gem cleanup
```

from the root of my app and followed it up by running

```
bundle install
```

It worked for me.