# Activesupport / Multi json: "Did not recognize your adapter specification"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I have a Ruby 1.9.3 / Rails 3.1 project with the following in the gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.12'
gem 'json'
gem 'multi_json', '1.7.7'
```

That version of `rails` sets `activesupport` to 3.1.12 as well. I'm not sure what the exact cause of the problem is, but when running `bundle exec rake test`, I got the error:

```
/home/user/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems/multi_json-1.7.7/lib/multi_json.rb:121:in 'rescue in load_adapter': Did not recognize your adapter specification. (ArgumentError)
...
(more stack trace, including activesupport methods)
```

Fortunately I found a solution! See below.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: My original answer is outdated and incorrect; read it if you please, but please read the **updated information at the bottom**.

After viewing a ton of other questions such as these ones:

[OmniAuth Login With Twitter - "Did not recognize your adapter specification." Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470342/omniauth-login-with-twitter-did-not-recognize-your-adapter-specification-er)
[Capistrano deploy: "Did not recognize your adapter specification" during assets:precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220485/capistrano-deploy-did-not-recognize-your-adapter-specification-during-assets)
https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/issues/132

I hadn't found a solution, so I dove into the library and determined that load_adapter was receiving the parameter "JSONGem". The alias was failing, and the method attempted to load

`/home/user/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems/multi_json-1.7.7/lib/multi_json/adapters/JSONGem.rb`

This file doesn't exist, but `.../json_gem.rb` does exist! So I modified load adapter as follows:

```
def load_adapter(new_adapter)
    # puts "new_adapter: #{new_adapter}"                              # Debugging
    # puts "new_adapater.class: #{new_adapter.class}"                 # Debugging
    case new_adapter
    when String, Symbol
      new_adapter = ALIASES.fetch(new_adapter.to_s, new_adapter)
      new_adapter = "json_gem" if new_adapter =~ /^jsongem$/i         # I added this line
      # puts "final adapter: #{new_adapter}"                          # debugging
      require "multi_json/adapters/#{new_adapter}"
      klass_name = new_adapter.to_s.split('_').map(&:capitalize) * ''
      MultiJson::Adapters.const_get(klass_name)
    when NilClass, FalseClass
      load_adapter default_adapter
    when Class, Module
      new_adapter
    else
      raise NameError
    end
  rescue NameError, ::LoadError
   raise ArgumentError, 'Did not recognize your adapter specification.'
  end
```

This fixed the problem for me. It's probably not an optimal solution (ideally I would understand WHY the ALIASES.fetch failed, if that is indeed what happened, and fix that), but if your problem is similar then hopefully this quick fix can help.

---

**Update**

It's not viable for deployability reasons to modify someone else's gem. Fortunately I found the root cause of the problem. In `project_root/config/initializers/security_patches.rb`, we had the line

```
 ActiveSupport::JSON.backend = "JSONGem"
```

This was the recommended fix to a [security bug in older versions of rails](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Rails-developers-close-another-extremely-critical-flaw-1793511.html). Now that we are on a newer version of rails (i.e, > 3.0), we can simply replace "JSONGem" with "json_gem" (which is what my original modification was doing, in a roundabout way) and not worry about the security issue.