# Rails and Passenger -- did not recognize adapter specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a Rails 3.1.12 application using Ruby 1.9.3 and Phusion Passenger 5.0.4 and I am getting this error:

```
Did not recognize your adapter specification (cannot load such file -- multi_json/adapters/jsongem). (MultiJson::AdapterError)
```

My Gemfile contains:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.12' 
gem 'json' 
gem 'multi_json', '1.7.7'
```

From Googling and other StackOverflow answers I have found that most people have solved this issue by downgrading multi_json to version 1.7.7, but I am already using this version of multi_json.

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380667/activesupport-multi-json-did-not-recognize-your-adapter-specification) is partway there, but requires editing gem code and that is not viable for deploying.

Any tips, pointers or solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your app you're probably doing

```
MultiJson.adapter = :jsongem
```

when you should be doing

```
MultiJson.adapter = :json_gem
```

assuming that you want to use the json gem for your json needs

Comment: This is exactly the problem. We had patched Rails (we upgraded recently) to deal with the yaml vulnerability and had a call to ActiveSupport::JSON.backend = "JSONGem". Changing that to json_gem solved the problem. Thank you for taking the time to reply.